# MIME for preview text in subject line of email

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, email, visual-studio-code, mime

I want to show preview text with subject in subject line not the body of the email. before this I'm showing body f the email with the subject in subject line.I'm using the Golang AWS SES-v2 https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sesv2 package for sending emails

I want the MIME to show preview text

Full MIME for preview text

Comment: This looks pretty much the same as the question you [asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78203882/11810946) (and does not add any detail so will be closed again - please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Yesterday, I provided a [link to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888872/how-to-define-html-email-preheader) that demonstrates the html required to do what I believe you are trying to achieve (but did not receive any response).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "MIME for preview". There is no standard to mark a specific part of the mail for preview.

If the mail client shows parts of the mail body in addition to the subject of the mail in preview is very specific to the mail client or maybe even its configuration. This means it will also differ between clients and one cannot rely on anything here.

Therefore, whatever you do it might be rendered differently in different mail clients.